# Parse server on AWS ElasticBeanStalk does not stream .mp4 PFFile to AVPlayer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-server

Parse server hosted on AWS ElasticBeanStalk(deployed with AWS button) cannot stream .mp4 PFFile saved in mongodb on AWS EC2 (EBS) to iOS AVPlayer and Safari browser.

Video plays on Chrome browser but does not play on my iOS app or Safari browser. [video link](http://parseserver-fmp42-env.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/parse/files/1S22JRBPse4F5vXbpnvP666mbBAqruD6VxZrbRfi/11990ed054321d7aefba75f734896651_2016-06-20%2018-03-57%200000_LWyt213QSG.mp4)

Videos hosted on parse service play with no problem.

Error I get on iOS:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x13fb86740 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12939 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The server is not correctly configured., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the S3 file adapter for storing my videos fixed it!